# Connecting two routers with wired connection into the same network

Tags: router

I have a wireless router (router 1) already up and running without computer attached.
I have another wireless router (router 2) that I'd like to attach to wired connection and attach computer to it. 
When I tried setting up router 2, it makes different WiFi with its own SSID. I'd like to have router 1 and router 2 on the same network (and use the same SSID). is there a way to achieve

Router 1 and router 2 are physically far apart so i don't want to run ethernet cable between them.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the manufactures and models of the routers?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not run a cable you can try to connect the routers by WiFi.
Some routers can be Wifi client & Wifi Access Point at the same time.
If you have one of those router2 being a client can connect to the Wifi of router1 and at the same time being a access point and let other clients connect to it.

If you like to use the same SSID you will have to make sure the router2 does not try to connect to it self.

I've done once something similar (being client and accesspoint) at the same time with [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org/)

Maybe it would be easier for you just to have a WiFi Repeater, or to run the Wifi Router in Repeater mode, if it supports it